# What is the value of the expression: $(1+\frac 12)(1+\frac 13)(1+\frac 14)...(1+\frac {1}{2004})(1+\frac {1}{2005})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

What is the value of the expression: $(1+\frac 12)(1+\frac 13)(1+\frac 14)...(1+\frac {1}{2004})(1+\frac {1}{2005})$? This question appeared on the UKMT senior maths challenge 2005, and I can't find an adequate method for a solution given its context i.e. without a calculator, and it should only take 3 to 4 minutes. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: When you're given a long complicated expression like this, your best bet is to compute the first few pieces of it to see if there is an obvious pattern that emerges. From there, you can do a second pass to come up with the general expression. In your case, $(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{4}{2}$. Then multiplying the next part you have $\frac{4}{2}(1+\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{4}{2}\cdot \frac{5}{4} = \frac{5}{2}$. The pattern then becomes pretty clear.

Answer (score 15):

Hint: $$1+\frac 1n=\frac {n+1}n$$

Answer (score 3):

It can be seen directly that the finite products give a telescoping product as was demonstrated in the other answers. If this is unclear, another approach is to apply a logarithm to the product and work out the resulting series:

Let $L_{2005} = \left(1+\frac12\right)\left( 1+ \frac13 \right) \cdots \left( 1 + \frac1{2005}\right)$.

Then $$\ln(L_{2005}) = \sum_{n=2}^{2005} \ln\left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{2005} \left( \ln(n+1) - \ln(n) \right).$$

This gives a telescoping sum. We can work out what the result should be by working out some smaller cases.

$$\ln(L_{3}) = \ln(3)-\ln(2) + \ln(4) - \ln(3) = \ln(4) - \ln(2)$$

$$\ln(L_4) = \ln(L_3) + (\ln(5) - \ln(4)) = \ln(5) - \ln(2)$$

Thus we see that this satisfies the general form:

$$\ln(L_N) = \ln(N+1) - \ln(2).$$

Thus $\ln(L_{2005}) = \ln(2006) - \ln(2) = \ln(1003)$ and $L_{2005} = 1003$.

Though, it was unnecessary to apply the logarithm to arrive at this result, often logarithms are used on an infinite (or large) product in order to apply our intuitions about the convergence or sums of series.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mark Bennet's hint, we have: $$1 + \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n+1}{n}$$

So that your product becomes $$\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{5}{4} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \cdots \frac{2005}{2004} \cdot \frac{2006}{2005} = \frac{2006}{2} = 1003$$

Comment: Essentially the same as Mark Bennet's hint

Comment: Except mine is not a hint, it's the full solution? This allows the OP to verify the answer or if the hint was not enough help him see how the hint is to be used.

Comment: I think there is an expected etiquette of acknowledging the fact that you are using an answer similar to that of another responder.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** One may write
$$
\prod_2^{2005} \left(1+\frac 1k\right)=\prod_2^{2005} \frac {k+1}k
$$ and observe that **factors telescope**.

Comment: Essentially the same as Mark Bennet's hint